# How to deal with a form that the button submit placed in parent component

Tags: react-hook-form, react-typescript

I use react hook form, i have a form which my submit button placed in the parent component. my question is how i deal with the loading state of the button, when i try to call an api?. I have tried to use isSubmitting state, but again i dont know how to make that state visible for another component. i am glad to receive an answer. my real problem is how i can make state 'isSubmitting' able to read by my parent component, so i can do loading button after i call the api.

this for the parents

```
const ForceEditPassword = () => {

    const childRef = useRef<any>();
    return (

        <>
            <div className='force-edit-password d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center'>

                <div className='inner d-flex justify-items-center align-items-center flex-column'>

                    <FormEditPassword ref={childRef} />

                    <button className='bg-primary rounded bottom-0 start-50 translate-middle-x'
                        onClick={() => { childRef.current?.onSubmit(); }}>
                        <p className='text-light m-0 p-2 text-capitalize rounded'>
                            Simpan
                        </p>
                    </button>

                </div>

            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default ForceEditPassword;
```